# Shared/Static Variable Should Be Nothing but Isn't - what gives?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have the following code:

```
Public Class TestClass
    Public Sub Main()
        If theGlobal IsNot Nothing Then Throw New Exception("What gives!")
    End Sub

    Private Shared theGlobal As Object = Nothing
    Private Shared ReadOnly Property Global
        Get
            If theGlobal Is Nothing Then
                theGlobal = New Object()
            End If

            Return theGlobal 
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Am stumped... Why is theGlobal object NOT Nothing?

Comment: Can you show the code that is running the Test() method?  Specifically, everything before that piece of code would be nice.

Comment: This code does not make sense. Simple change to Private Shared theGlobal As Object = New Object(), and removing If theGlobal part will solve all your troubles.

Comment: This was a dumb piece of code just to reproduce the situation. But @Jon was right, I was in the debugger and in my "Watch" window I had the property - just didn't realize it because the Watch window was hidden and I was looking at the "Locals" and "Immediate" window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that's really your code, my guess is that you're running this in the debugger with a breakpoint, and the watch window is evaluating the property, which is initializing `theGlobal`.

Just a guess, based on what I've seen before in similar situations.

If that doesn't help, try to write a short but complete console application which reproduces the problem, and which we can all run.

Comment: you da man! Spent like 2 hours trying to figure out what the heck is going on... Had the property in the "Watch" window all this time... Ughhhhh!

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant

```
If Global Is Nothing Then Throw New Exception("What gives!")
```

You have to access the Global property for the field to be initialized, according to your code.

Comment: No, the point of his question is that he's *expecting* it to be nothing if he doesn't access the property... but it's not.